# Missing artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-samples-resources:jar:8.2.8

Tags: java, maven, docx4j

I am trying to convert html to docx in java spring.
I used docx4j for this, but have some problems.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I put these dependencies but it says "Missing artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-samples-resources:jar:8.2.8" even I didn't put any dependency for docx4j-samples-resources.
Or there is any other easy way to convert HTML to Docx in Java ?
please help me if anyone knows this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-importxhtml-8-2-0-released-t2967.html#p10130 which says you can exclude it like so:

```
             <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
                        <version>8.2.0</version>
                        <exclusions>
                                <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>docx4j-samples-resources</artifactId>
                                </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                </dependency>
```

That dep just contains sample config files: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/docx4j-samples-resources/src/main/resources and as such isn't in Maven Central.